# Is a vector field a section or a tangent vector?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, vector-fields, tangent-bundle

Is a vector field a section or a tangent vector? This question arose when I read two statements in a book named `geometric control of mechanical system`. The first statement is the following (p. 84).

> $C^r$-vector field on $M$ is an element of $\Gamma^r(TM)$, i.e., a
>   $C^r$-section of the tangent bundle of $M$.

Here, $M$ is a manifold and $\Gamma^r(TM)$ is a set of sections of $TM$. But, after that, I found the following statement (p. 173)

> Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to Q$ be a $C^2$-curve. A variation of $\gamma$ is a
>   $C^2$-map $\theta: J \times [a,b]\to Q$ with the properties
>   (i) $J \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval for which $0\in \mathrm{int}(J)$,
>   (ii)
>   $\theta(0, t)=\gamma(t), \forall t\in[a, b]$,
>   (iii) $\theta(s, a)=\gamma(a) \land \theta(s, b)=\gamma(b), \forall s\in J$
>   The infinitesimal variation associated with a variation $\theta$ is the
>   vector field along $\gamma$ given by $\delta\theta(t)=\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}\theta(s, t)\in T_{\gamma(t)}Q$.

According to the first statement, a vector field is a section, which is a map from $M$ to $TM$. However, according to the second statement, a vector field is an element of tangent space $T_{\gamma(t)}Q$, which means a vector field is a tangent vector. How should I interpret these two statements with consistency?

Comment: If you evaluate a map $M\to TM$ at a point you get an element of $TM$, that is a tangent vector

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I know.. but still those two are different things. Is that usual in mathematics that first saying something is a map then after that saying that is a vector? (sorry, I'm new to mathematics)

Comment: Well, they call it *a vector field along $\gamma(t)$* it is different than *a vector field on $M$*. So no contradiction. Of cause, the two object kind of convey the same idea: a smooth assignments of vectors from tangent spaces to $M$. The difference is in the parts of $M$ that you are interested in. The first one talks about the whole $M$ the second only about curve on $M$.

Comment: The second object is a function (depending on $t$), so, as $t$ varies, you get different tangent vectors.  It's describing a map to $TM$ by describing the image point-by-point.

Comment: It may be better to see this in terms of the tangent bundle and flows. Lee has [a very good treatment of these concepts](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387217529)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector field is a section of the natural projection map $TM\to M$. You should imagine choosing a tangent vector at *every point* smoothly.

This infinitesimal variation you mentioned is a way of giving a vector field along a smooth path (not the entire manifold). The formula you gave following $\delta\theta(t)$ is telling you which tangent vector to stick onto the point $\gamma(t)$.